# Weights on cyclic orderings

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, permutations, cyclic-orders

Are there standard or known weights/metrics on cyclic orders?

[Cyclic orderings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order) are different ways of listing elements from a finite set, where you call two lists the same if they differ only by a rotation.  For example, the ways that 4 people can sit at a circular table, where you ignore rotation of the table.

So the following 4 rankings of a 4-item set should be considered the same:

```
[2,1,4,3]
[1,4,3,2]
[4,3,2,1]
[3,2,1,4]
```

You can think of this as arranging the 4 items on a circular list, with no particular top, but a definite direction.

I would like to compare different cyclic orderings in a meaningful way.  I have learned that there are many well-known ways of assigning distance or weight to non-cyclic orderings (a.k.a. permutations!).  For example:

- Kendall $\tau$
- Transposition distance (Cayley)
- Ulam metric
- Hamming weight
- $\ell_1$ norm

But these give different weights to permutations which correspond to the same cyclic ordering.

---

A first simple idea is the following: given a permutation $a$, count the number of $i$ such that $a(i+1) \neq a(i) +1$, where $0 \leq i \leq n$ and index addition is performed modulo $n$.

A natural variation on this idea would sum $|a(i+1) - (a(i)+1)|$.

I haven't thought about either of these too carefully yet.  Do they appear in the literature somewhere?  Some nontrivial internet searching hasn't turned anything up.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58782/cyclic-permutations-but-not-what-you-think - Woodall's "Cyclic-order graphs and Zarankiewicz's crossing-number conjecture" is the most interesting paper on this, from my perspective, because it actually constructs the graph of these things under a certain definition of this distance (one I like best).  I do not know of any *theoretical* discussion of the issue you mention, though I'm glad to hear of Dima's *computational* one - and if it was actually more theoretical in that paper than I though, he'll let me know :) which I will find useful.

Comment: we (and Woodall, and Kleitman) define the graph on these $(n-1)!$ elements of $S_n$, so that two such elements are adjacent if one needs to swap two adjacent positions to get one from the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cyclic permutations, and a need to define distances on them, pops up in literature on graph crossing numbers, e.g. we used it in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404142

It probably goes back all the way to at least

D.J. Kleitman, The crossing number of $K_5$. J. Combinatorial Theory 9 (1970), 315–323.